# DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) not working in PDO statement

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am converting my site to use prepared statements instead of mysqli. However I have come across an issue which I know worked using mysqli but it doesn't work using prepared statements. I want to delete all records that are 5 minutes older than than the time recorded in the database which in this case is stored in column last_fail_login.
I am not getting an error but it delete's every record in the db table no matter how many minutes old it is which is not correct.
I have pasted the code below:

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM login_fail WHERE `last_fail_login` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)");
$stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: It delete's every record in the db table no matter how many minutes old it is

Comment: `>=` instead of `<`? At the moment all records are deleted older than now - 5 minutes. In case you want to delete all records failed in the last 5 minutes you have to use `>=`.

Comment: There is no difference which api you are using to run a query. Which makes this question odd topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally worked out why this wasn't working. I still understand how this affected it but once I set my timezone using `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` the query worked. Strange that I didn't have to set this when using MYSQLI. Thanks for all suggestions.